# Can anyone explain Android storage space?

Tags: storage

My Hannspree tablet running Android 4.4.2 has 3 distinct storage locations:

- Internal storage - 1GB,
- Internal SD card - 12GB,
- Removable SD card - 32GB.

What's the point of the internal SD card if all the apps insist on using the Internal storage of 1GB? Most of that 1GB is occupied by Google apps I can't delete.

---

More information:

I thought I had moved all the apps that were possible, but I found a few more. Available space has now increased from 119MB to 190MB. With one exception, all the Google apps do not have that option and also many of the others including many of the real space hogs.

There's a trick I have found useful but its effects are temporary. What I do is uninstall all the Google app updates and that free up around 400MB. When the updates are reapplied, there is still an increase in space. Uninstalling and reinstalling apps like [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) also has a useful result.

There seems to be some sort of software level sensor which says that space cannot be allowed to fall below about 100MB. Installing a new app with size 2MB or updating an existing one can fail when space left is 100MB. Perhaps you are familiar with Zinio. It quotes available space as 12GB and then puts data into the 1GB partition?

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 3):

You can always resize your partitions (if you have root). I've doubled my /data partition (the place where apps are stored), by reducing the emulated SD card and enlarging the data partition. It is not the easiest task, but it may be worth your while since I think that your device is not much usable otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The first partition (Internal Storage 1GB) is the actual block of system memory. Things like the OS are stored here. The second (Internal SD Card 12GB) is an emulated SD card, but still technically part of your system memory. Most apps want to install to what they see as the system memory by default, which in your case is partitioned into a 1GB chunk. Have you tried moving your apps to the internal memory/SD card?

Comment: Jason, didn't you mess up `/system` and `/data` partitions? The former is where "the OS" (and system apps) are stored, and is read-only in normal mode. `/data` is where the user-installed apps go to, and that's a different partition. For details, see our [storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Open ES File Explorer and under download manager select "enable ES download manager". ES download manager has the 12gb SD card as its default location. If it's not the default you can set it to be.

Big apps are now downloading onto the 12bg partition.

Comment: This'll work for downloaded files, but certainly not for apps installed.